# WriteStream with format('console') in Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: azure, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a stream of data which I can write to an in-memory table with pyspark and query with sql from there:

```
transformeddata.writeStream\
   .format("memory")\
   .queryName("transformeddatatable")\
   .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds')\
   .start()\
   .awaitTermination(20)  # write the data for 20 seconds into the memory table from the stream
```

In the next cell I can query the data:

```
%%sql
SELECT * FROM transformeddatatable
```

This works well and the data appears in the in-memory table `transformeddatatable`.

However, I cannot manage to display the data directly in the console:

```
transformeddata.writeStream\
   .format("console")\
   .outputMode("append")\
   .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
   .option("checkpointLocation", "tmp/checkpoint/streamtoconsole/")\
   .start()\
   .awaitTermination(20)
```

The only thing that gets returned to the console is a boolean value of `False` once it terminates after 20 seconds.

In a lot of examples online the code above works. I'm dumbfounded what I do wrong - is it a problem of Azure's Synapse Notebook? Does it only work with Databricks?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Sadly no. If you find something, make sure to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider two important factors:

1 - You can use synapse's Datalake storage account open on the Internet or using select networks. If your synapse datalake storage account is using select networks, you will need to use private endpoints to be able to connect to synapse datalake.

2 - You must also grant the Storage Blob Contributor RBAC permission on the synapse storage account datalake to the user or Service Principal that will execute the commands.

After that you will probably be able to run.

My code below:

```
 dfFinal 
    .select($"partition", $"enqueuedTime", $"newBody") 
    .groupBy(window($"enqueuedTime", "1 minute")) 
    .count() 
    .writeStream 
    .outputMode("update") 
    .option("truncate", "false") 
    .format("console") 
    .start() 
    .awaitTermination()
```

and the result:

```
 -------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+-----+
|window                                    |count|
+------------------------------------------+-----+
|{2022-10-17 15:47:00, 2022-10-17 15:48:00}|17   |
|{2022-10-17 20:46:00, 2022-10-17 20:47:00}|15   |
|{2022-10-18 22:53:00, 2022-10-18 22:54:00}|5    |
|{2022-10-19 14:36:00, 2022-10-19 14:37:00}|8    |
|{2022-10-19 15:17:00, 2022-10-19 15:18:00}|3    |
|{2022-10-20 18:15:00, 2022-10-20 18:16:00}|8    |
|{2022-10-21 09:41:00, 2022-10-21 09:42:00}|3    |
|{2022-10-17 15:48:00, 2022-10-17 15:49:00}|28   |
|{2022-10-18 16:59:00, 2022-10-18 17:00:00}|7    |
|{2022-10-19 13:57:00, 2022-10-19 13:58:00}|5    |
|{2022-10-18 18:42:00, 2022-10-18 18:43:00}|10   |
|{2022-10-20 14:49:00, 2022-10-20 14:50:00}|11   |
|{2022-10-18 21:47:00, 2022-10-18 21:48:00}|2    |
|{2022-10-19 22:31:00, 2022-10-19 22:32:00}|6    |
|{2022-10-19 16:37:00, 2022-10-19 16:38:00}|13   |
|{2022-10-19 22:35:00, 2022-10-19 22:36:00}|13   |
|{2022-10-20 17:43:00, 2022-10-20 17:44:00}|12   |
|{2022-10-19 14:39:00, 2022-10-19 14:40:00}|4    |
|{2022-10-14 22:26:00, 2022-10-14 22:27:00}|12   |
|{2022-10-18 22:17:00, 2022-10-18 22:18:00}|2    |
+------------------------------------------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Thanks for correcting my sentence. I will also keep trying to reach the reputation of 50 to be able to comment.

Comment: Please [edit] the answer to explain the two different situations. What in case if? What in case if not?